# Why is exit(0); giving me a std:string... error?

Tags: c++, exit

I'm new to C++. I decided to not watch the next tutorial and put my skills to use, by making a funny Mind Reader application. I'm pleased with myself, however, even though I've ironed out most bugs, I still have one concerning the exit function. I read the C++ documentation for it, and I'm not sure what I did wrong. I did exit(0);. I  have a very weird error, which is:

```
no match for call to '(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (int)
```

I have searched online, however I am still unaware of what the problem is. My error is on line 59 (marked in the code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declaring variables to be used later
    string name;
    string country;
    int age;

    //header goes below
   cout << "#######################################";
           " @@@@@@@@@@@@ MIND READER @@@@@@@@@@@@"
           "#######################################\n\n";

    //asks if the user would like to continue and in not, terminates
    cout << "Would like you to have your mind read? Enter y for yes and n for no." << endl;
    cout << "If you do not choose to proceed, this program will terminate." << endl;
    string exitOrNot;
    //receives user's input
    cin >> exitOrNot;
    //deals with input if it is 'y'
    if (exitOrNot == "y"){
        cout << "Okay, first you will need to sync your mind with this program. You will have to answer the following questions to synchronise.\n\n";

        //asks questions
        cout << "Firstly, please enter your full name, with correct capitalisation:\n\n";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Now please enter the country you are in at the moment:\n\n";
        cin >> country;

        cout << "This will be the final question; please provide your age:\n\n";
        cin >> age;

        //asks the user to start the sync
        cout << "There is enough information to start synchronisation. Enter p to start the sync...\n\n";
        string proceed;
        cin >> proceed;
        //checks to see if to proceed and does so
        if (proceed == "p"){
            //provides results of mind read
            cout << "Sync complete." << endl;
            cout << "Your mind has been synced and read.\n\n";
            cout << "However, due to too much interference, only limited data was aquired from your mind." << endl;
            cout << "Here is what was read from your mind:\n\n";

            //puts variables in sentence
            cout << "Your name is " << name << " and you are " << age << " years old. You are based in " << country << "." << endl << "\n\n";

            cout << "Thanks for using Mind Reader, have a nice day. Enter e to exit." << endl;
            //terminates the program the program
            string exit;
            cin >> exit;
            if (exit == "e"){
                exit(0);       // <------------- LINE 59
            }

        }

    }
    //terminates the program if the input is 'n'
    if (exitOrNot == "n"){
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 4):

The local variable `exit` shadows other identifiers from outer scopes with the same name.

To illustrate with a smaller example:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    {
        int i;
        i = 0; // assign to the "nearest" i
        // the other i cannot be reached from this scope
    }
}
```

Since the only `exit` visible is an object of type `std::string`, the compiler sees `exit(0)` as a call to `operator()(int)` and throws a hissy fit when it doesn't find one among `std::string` members.

You can either qualify the name (`std::exit(0);`) or rename the variable. And since all of your code is in `main` you can simply say `return 0;` instead.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, but I'm really confused about your answer, as I'm literally 15 episodes in of thenewboston's C++ lessons. However, the guy below answered my question  as well, and I've commented. Could you help me there? Thanks.

Comment: @IrshadAM If you tell me what exactly is confusing about my answer I'll be happy to amend.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`. It's the exact same thing. Also, you can only input one word into a `cin`. Instead, use `getline(cin, string name);` If it still doesn't work, add a `cin.ignore();` before your `getline(cin, string name);`, like this:

```
//stuff
string country;
cout << "Now please enter the country you are in at the moment:\n\n";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, country);
//stuff
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is arrising because you declared a standard keyword as  the name of a local variable.
Now as the local variable is of type sting it is not able to take it as its value.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell which variable is the culprit here?

Comment: @IrshadAM There's only one `exit` local variable in your code.

Comment: Well, thanks for all the help guys. 
The problem: Dear god, my stupidity.

Well my program works now, I only have to fix the header.
Thanks for all the help!
I love stack exchange!
Sorry for the spam btw!

Comment: `exit` is **not** a keyword. Aside from that, this answer is correct.